# could add GD support to php interrupt a website services?

Tags: php, gd

For one website, I need to add a litle script who resize images in php. For that, I used the GD functions. That worked very well in the dev machine, the problem is that in production doesn't work because php GD support isn't installed.
The things is, I'am not expert in server configurations and maintenance (my experience is mostly develop, and in others jobs other people were in charge of the servers, but this company is very small, so...), and I have a little fear that, if simple I install php-gd support, something wrong could happens to the productions server.

Any advice would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is the possibility of something going wrong during the install, this can be mitigated by backups. Only thing I could imagine on the php side is concerning method definition - if somebody defined a method with the **exact** same name of a predefined mod_gd one, it will break.

If you want to be really sure: get a full backup of the production server, install it in a VM and test adding the GD support to it. If it doesn't break the VM install, it won't break the production server either.